# EJB3 Client Lookup

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am trying to invoke a EJB from a standalone Java client, getting the below error.

**Lookup code**

```
String localJNDIName = "ejbremote:gcmsnew/gcmsutilbeans.jar/CustomerSurveyManageQstBean#com.smbcgroup.gcms.utility.bl.survey.CustomerSurveyManageQstRemote";
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
GCMSBaseRemote bean = (GCMSBaseRemote)ic.lookup(localJNDIName);
```

**Exception**

> javax.naming.ConfigurationException: NamingManager.getURLContext
>   cannot find the factory for this scheme: ejbremote    at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.checkForUrlContext(CNContextImpl.java:471)
>     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:160)    at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.test.EJBClientTest.main(EJBClientTest.java:18)

**Environment**

RAD 7.5, EJB3. Websphere Application Server 7.0.

Answer (score 3):

The ejbremote scheme does not exist in WebSphere Application Server (even though "ejblocal" does exist).  Try using a **ejb/** prefix instead of **ejbremote:**.

For more information, see the [EJB application bindings overview](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html) topic in the InfoCenter.

Comment: It worked like a magic. Can you give some pointers to some reference reading to understand more on this?

Comment: I've added an InfoCenter link, but let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: @BrettKail the link seems to be broken.

Comment: It appears IBM broke the link.  I am no longer familiar enough with the product to find a replacement.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a standalone ("thin") client may be you should try something like this:

```
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
   properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809"); //localhost=the host where your EJB is located, 2809=BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS port
   Context initCtx = new InitialContext(properties);
   Object homeObject = initCtx.lookup("com.smbcgroup.gcms.utility.bl.survey.CustomerSurveyManageQstRemote"); //by default the JNDI name of your Remote Interface is its full class name
   // Narrow to a real object
   csmo = (CustomerSurveyManageQstRemote) javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(homeObject, com.smbcgroup.gcms.utility.bl.survey.CustomerSurveyManageQstRemote.class);
```

You should also have the appropriate Websphere Jars in your classpath in order to make the above calls.

Comment: I have using other names like, java:global, ejblocal, those didnt work and giving some weird errors.  This worked for me .initCtx.lookup("com.smbcgroup.gcms.utility.bl.survey.CustomerSurveyManageQstRemote"); //by default the JNDI name of your Remote Interface

Answer (score 1):

For remote lookup

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;  
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ServiceLocator {
    static String url = "corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809";
    static String initial = "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory";  
    static String jndi = "ejb/enterprise_app_name/ejb_web_project_name.jar/ejb_name#name.of.remote.impl.interface";


    private static ServiceLocator serviceLocator = null;  

    InitialContext context = null;

    private ServiceLocator() throws NamingException, IOException { 

        Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String> (); 
        env.put("java.naming.provider.url",  url ); 
        env.put("java.naming.factory.initial",  initial );
        context = new InitialContext(env);
    }

    public synchronized static ServiceLocator getInstance() throws NamingException, IOException {

        if (serviceLocator == null) {
            serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator(); 
        }

        return serviceLocator;
    }  

    public Object getService(String jndiName) throws NamingException {
        return context.lookup(jndiName); 
    }

    public <T>T getRemoteObject(Class<T> remoteInterfaceClass) {
        try {

            return (T)javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow( context.lookup(jndi), remoteInterfaceClass);

        } catch (NamingException nexc) {

            nexc.printStackTrace(); 

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

For local lookup

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;  
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ServiceLocator {
    static String url = "iiop://localhost";
    static String initial = "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory";  
    static String jndi = "ejblocal:enterprise_app_name/ejb_web_project_name.jar/ejb_name#name.of.local.impl.interface";



    private static ServiceLocator serviceLocator = null;  

    InitialContext context = null;

    private ServiceLocator() throws NamingException, IOException { 

        Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String> (); 
        env.put("java.naming.provider.url",  url ); 
        env.put("java.naming.factory.initial",  initial );
        context = new InitialContext(env);
    }

    public synchronized static ServiceLocator getInstance() throws NamingException, IOException {

        if (serviceLocator == null) {
            serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator(); 
        }

        return serviceLocator;
    }  

    public Object getService(String jndiName) throws NamingException {
        return context.lookup(jndiName); 
    }

    public Object getService() throws NamingException {
        return context.lookup(jndi); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the stub file to invoke the EJB, so first generate the stub file. In websphere there is utility available in the appserver bin folder createEJBStubs.