# What's the default JNDI name of an EJB in Websphere Application Server 7 (WAS)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jndi, websphere-7

In the Administration COnsole of WAS 7, on the **Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > application > EJB JNDI names** section, I have a table with four columns :

- EJB Module (e.g. ProjectEJB.jar)
- EJB (e.g. BeanBO )
- URI (e.g. ProjectEJB.jar, META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
- Target resource JNDI Name (with empty fields)

Something like this :

[image]

What's the jndi name of my LogWriter bean ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below you have table with default names. Each bean gets short and long form. You can override default using ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file or during installation via console. During module startup bindings will be visible in SysyemOut.log

You can read about default bindings here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/info/iseriesexp/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html

```
Description                              Binding pattern
Short form local interfaces and homes    ejblocal:<package.qualified.interface>
Short form remote interfaces and homes   <package.qualified.interface>
Long form local interfaces and homes     ejblocal:<component-id>#<package.qualified.interface>
Long form remote interfaces and homes    ejb/<component-id>#<package.qualified.interface>

The component-id defaults to <application-name>/<module-jar-name>/<ejb-name>
```

Comment: So if jndi configured in ejb-jar.xml, will it override the EJB JNDI lookup configured in WebSphere admin console?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare - no, the JNDI configuration in the console always takes a precedence from any descriptors to allow you for manual override after deployment.

Answer (score 4):

One can set it by adding a file **META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml**  - something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <session name="LogWriter" simple-binding-name="my/ejb/LogWriterService"/>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

We used to have a script to generate these server-specific files for the different vendors.

Comment: Thanks Ed !, as you said, this is for a custom JDNI. I have tried to change it in the Administration Console but there wasn't and 'Ok' or 'Save' button, but with the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936264/539783][2]

For local lookup :

```
String jndi = "ejblocal:enterprise_app_name/ejb_web_project_name.jar/ejb_name#name.of.local.impl.interface";
```

For remote lookup :

```
String jndi = "ejb/enterprise_app_name/ejb_web_project_name.jar/ejb_name#name.of.remote.impl.interface";
```

Example :

**ejblocal:ServicesEAR/LogWriter.jar/LogWriter#ILogWriter**

UPDATE : It doesn't work in some cases.