# JNDI Lookup of local EJB (no @EJB)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I have a requirement where I'm asked to load both remote and local EJBs with a JNDI lookup, so without the @EJB annotation.

My EJB is defined as follows:

```
@Remote
public interface MyObjectInterfaceRemote extends MyObjectInterface {

}
```

---

```
@Local
public interface MyObjectInterfaceLocal extends MyObjectInterface {

}
```

---

```
public interface MyObjectInterface {
    // A bunch of methods which both remote and local ejbs will inherit
}
```

---

```
@Remote(MyObjectInterfaceRemote.class)
@Local(MyObjectInterfaceLocal.class)
public class MyObjectEJB implements MyObjectInterfaceLocal, MyObjectInterfaceRemote {
    //implementation of all methods inherited from MyObjectInterface.
}
```

I'm using this code to lookup the remote EJB:

```
private MyObjectInterfaceRemote getEJB() throws NamingException {
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    return (MyObjectInterfaceRemote) context.lookup(MyObjectInterfaceRemote.class.getName());
}
```

It works fine, but if I make another method like this:

```
private MyObjectInterfaceLocal getLocalEJB() throws NamingException {
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    return (MyObjectInterfaceLocal) context.lookup(MyObjectInterfaceLocal.class.getName());
}
```

I get

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
Context: Backslash-PCNode03Cell/nodes/Backslash-PCNode03/servers/server1, 
name: MyObjectInterfaceLocal: First component in name MyObjectInterfaceLocal not found. 
[Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: 
IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
[...]
```

What am I missing? Do I have to use something different to lookup a local ejb?

**Note:** If I use

```
@EJB
MyObjectInterfaceLocal ejb;
```

The local ejb gets succesfully loaded.

Comment: Yes, to lookup local interface you have to prefix it with `ejblocal:`. Check here [What's the default JNDI name of an EJB in Websphere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24005631/3701228) and notice ejblocal prefixes. You should see these names in the log during application startup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried below code?

```
context.lookup("ejblocal:"+MyObjectInterfaceLocal.class.getName())
```

Webshpere uses different default binding pattern for remote and local interfaces.